# What contain read property inside treeview in extjs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, treeview

I'm start to use ExtJs and absolutelly new in this framework. Can anybody explain me what I should declare inside `readPersons`? And where It must be stored or how can I referred this to my server side logic. My project based on ASP.NET MVC4 with entity framework where client side is based on ExtJs. Im try to poppulate TreeStore. And dont know how to declare and refer my readPerson varible. Which must get results from Action in my Server side logic.

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'PersonId',
    fields: [{ name: 'PersonId', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: root + 'Entity/GetPerson',
        api: {
            create: undefined,
            read: 'readPersons',
            update: undefined,
            destroy: undefined
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write server side code to return the json object, in ajax you have to call a URL with some query string which should return json object data... that will be used in extjs's store and all things...
and one thing in ASP.NET MVC, it have json return type right? use that return type and request that URL with or with out passing query string by help of ajax request used in ExtJs...

see this... http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax